# Tensorflow.js for Node.js Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'slice' must be a Tensor, but got object

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to convert a `Tensorflow.js` (ie the `tfjs` package) model example to the `Node.js` version (ie. `tfjs-node` package).

My import are the following:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
tf.setBackend('tensorflow');
```

This should be enough to load `tfjs` and `tfjs-node` bindings having `tensorflow` as default backend.

The code loads a pre-trained model built in shards (the tfjs model format), and it's as simple as:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var performance = require('perf_hooks').performance;

const model_path = 'file://' + __dirname + '/model/model.json';
const model_metadata = __dirname + '/model/metadata.json';

var text = 'this is a bad day';

tf.loadModel(model_path)
    .then(model => {

        let sentimentMetadata = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(model_metadata));
        //console.log(sentimentMetadata);

        let indexFrom = sentimentMetadata['index_from'];
        let maxLen = sentimentMetadata['max_len'];
        let wordIndex = sentimentMetadata['word_index'];

        console.log('indexFrom = ' + indexFrom);
        console.log('maxLen = ' + maxLen);

        console.log('model_type', sentimentMetadata['model_type']);
        console.log('vocabulary_size', sentimentMetadata['vocabulary_size']);
        console.log('max_len', sentimentMetadata['max_len']);

        const inputText =
            text.trim().toLowerCase().replace(/(\.|\,|\!)/g, '').split(/\s+/g); // tokenized

        console.log(inputText);

        // Look up word indices.
        const inputBuffer = tf.buffer([1, maxLen], 'float32');
        for (let i = 0; i < inputText.length; ++i) {
            const word = inputText[i];
            if (typeof wordIndex[word] == 'undefined') { // TODO(cais): Deal with OOV words.
                console.log(word, wordIndex[word]);
            }
            inputBuffer.set(wordIndex[word] + indexFrom, 0, i);
        }
        const input = inputBuffer.toTensor();

        console.log(text, "\n", input);

        const beginMs = performance.now();
        const predictOut = model.predict(inputBuffer);
        const score = predictOut.dataSync()[0];
        predictOut.dispose();
        const endMs = performance.now();
        console.log({ score: score, elapsed: (endMs - beginMs) });

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
```

I get this error while running:

```
Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'slice' must be a Tensor, but got object.
```

that means that my `input` object is not a `Tensor` object instance, even if I can clearly see in the logs that I have

```
Tensor {
  isDisposedInternal: false,
  size: 100,
  shape: [ 1, 100 ],
  dtype: 'float32',
  strides: [ 100 ],
  dataId: {},
  id: 22,
  rankType: '2' }
```

a `Tensor` object instance when getting the tensor from the input buffer:

```
const input = inputBuffer.toTensor();
```

I have asked to TF.js [group](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!mydiscussions/tfjs/wsTuFcSVLfQ), and some suggest that this could be due to an import error, and it could actually be.

My `package.json` is like

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^0.11.5",
    "@tensorflow/tfjs-node": "^0.1.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "yarn upgrade --pattern @tensorflow"
  }
}
```

The full example and the model are available [here](https://github.com/loretoparisi/tensorflow-node-examples/tree/master/sentiment).

Comment: The current version of tfjs is 0.11.6, but I don't think that's the problem, but you try it anyways.

Comment: thanks updated the repo to the latest build, but it does not fix it.

Comment: In the provided code in the other discussion `tfjs` and `tfjs-node` were the other way round. Did you try both ways and without setting the backend?

Comment: yes, thank you. I have tried this as well. There is a ongoing discussion about this issue on the tfjs group as well - https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!forum/tfjs